# CodenameOne SMB shared folder access

Tags: codenameone, smbj

I need to build a mobile app for Android and IOS that can read and write to a SMB2/3 network share.

Is this possible in CodenameOne? If so is there an example of how to do this?

If it is not possible in CodenameOne is there another framework that supports this functionality?

Thanks in advance for reviewing this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have any support for the SMB protocol. There is support for sockets but I think that would be a challenge to implement.

If the phone has access to the folder you can use the share operation and the user can pick the place where the file should be shared e.g. SMB, dropbox, etc.

Comment: Does CodenameOne support SFTP ?

Comment: No it doesn't. Only HTTP/S, TCP and WebSockets. You can implement anything you want using native APIs (which we support). E.g the websocket support is implemented as a library and isn't built-in.